# How to retrieve a QWidget from a list of opened windows

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

In some part of my project, I want to get the reference of a window, from a list of opened windows. 
So, i'm doing this way:

```
QWidget* WindowUtil::mainWindow() {
    QWidget* main_window = nullptr;
    for(QWidget *window: QApplication::allWidgets()){
        if(QString(window>metaObject()->className()).contains("Home")){
            main_window = window;
            break;
        }
    }
    return main_window;
}
```

`WindowUtil` is class of my project and `mainWindow()` is a static method.

However, this solution doesn't work. The compiler says:

```
error: incomplete type 'QApplication' used in nested name specifier
 for(QWidget *window : QApplication::allWidgets()){
                       ^
```

And I'm stuck here.

Comment: Try to add `#include <QApplication>` to the file where `WindowUtil::mainWindow()` is defined.

Comment: I had used `QApplication` elsewhere and did not need the #include. Maybe it's' cause this WindowUtil class has no relation with the QT. am i right ?

Comment: I don't know what is `WindowUtil` class, but probably yes. When you think you did not include `QApplication` header, you actually included it implicitly, as it was included to some other files, which were included to the file where you used `QApplication`. `#include` directive is recursive. For example, try to include any file to iself (without include guards) and you'll get an error like "#include nested too deeply".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the answer has been already posted as a comment, this error should mean (most of the time) that you have not included right header file, in this case: `<QApplication>` and your app cannot find the declarations for what it wants.

```
#include <QApplication>
```

instruction in the file that raises an error should be an efficient solution for your problem :)